# Oracle SQL: How to define loop counter value in a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop

(I am very new to SQL ...) I want to define a loop where the loop counter must be in a column (e.g. ID):

for i in (select ID from IDTable) loop 
...

Of course the above doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: the above should work, could you be a more precise in what you want to do? Aswell as you should include some desired output and input.

Comment: Can you use the `rownum` pseudocolumn in your use case?

Comment: Table IDTable has only one column (ID) and looks like this: (20,32,35,46, ...). I want the loop variable take all IDs in IDTable. When I try the above in Oracle SQL Dveloper, I get "Unknown command" error message.

Comment: I guess you forgot to start your code block with `begin`

Comment: What if I want the last value be selected like this? 

for i in 1..10 loop
for j in 1..(select ID from NameTable where Name=i) loop

I get this error for the second line (Select command):
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>

Comment: @ammoQ
When I try to use the counter of the outer for loop in the inner one, I get "expression is of wrong type" when I have: "name=i" 

`declare 
 loop2_final NUMBER;
BEGIN
 for i in (select ID from IDTable) loop
  select no INTO loop2_final from NameTable where  name=i;`
  for j in 1..loop2_final`

Comment: you always have to access the field: `...select no INTO loop2_final from NameTable where name=i.ID; ...`

Comment: @ammoQ
But `i` is one of the IDs (fields) selected from `IDTable`. `i.ID` is "invalid identificator"

Comment: And is it at all possible to have for loop counter selected from a table. According to this page, "After the body of the for loop executes, the value of the counter variable is increased or decreased.":
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_for_loop.htm

In my case, I don't want the variable to be increased. Next value should be taken from the selected list.

Comment: Then you have to replace `i` with another name for the cursor variable. `declare loop2_final NUMBER; BEGIN for FooBar in (select ID from IDTable) loop select no INTO loop2_final from NameTable where name=FooBar.ID;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for i in (select ID from IDTable) loop ...
>
> Of course the above doesn't work.

It does work, unless you are confused the value of loop counter and the `id` you are selecting in the for loop are same.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN
  3    (SELECT empno FROM emp
  4    )
  5    LOOP
  6      dbms_output.put_line(i.empno);
  7    END LOOP;
  8  END;
  9  /
7369
7499
7521
7566
7654
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844
7876
7900
7902
7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to use this loop counter in an insert command like this:

`FOR i IN (SELECT empno from emp) LOOP  
 INSERT INTO NewTable (NewID)  
 SELECT 10 * i  
END LOOP;`

But get "Expression is of wrong type" error for line `SELECT 10 * i`.

Comment: Of course it is incorrect. You just need to do `FOR i IN (SELECT empno from emp) LOOP INSERT INTO NewTable (NewID) VALUES(10 * i) END LOOP;`

Comment: @user1777530 Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it short, but missed one part. There is another filed (Field1) to be inserted which is "SELECT"ed: `FOR i IN (SELECT empno from emp) LOOP INSERT INTO NewTable (NewFiled,NewID) SELECT Filed1,10 * i FROM MyTable where ID = i END LOOP;`